# Image Picker in React native via expo in Android 6 is not working

Tags: react-native-image-picker

Im newbie to this tech, react native(android) and I cant find solution to my problem. My problem is, every time I pick an image my app will crash( this will happen if I use my samsung J7 prime, Android 6)
But when I try my app to my Iphone 6s(IOS 15) and in my Samsung(Android 13), my codes is working. But I want also to run in my android 6.

This is what I've tried.

```
 const pickImage = async () => {
    // No permissions request is necessary for launching the image library
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    }); //get the image from library in local image

    console.log(result);

    if (!result.canceled) {
      setGgcashProofImage(result.uri);
      setFilenameInput(result.uri.split("/").pop());
    }
  };

  const uploadImage = async () => {
    const blob = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.onload = function () {
        resolve(xhr.response);
      };
      xhr.onerror = function () {
        reject(new TypeError("Network request failed"));
      };
      xhr.responseType = "blob";
      xhr.open("GET", gcashProofImage, true);
      xhr.send(null);
    });
    const ref = firebase
      .storage()
      .ref()
      .child("Customer_GcashProof/" + fileNameInput);
    const snapshot = ref.put(blob, { contentType: "image/jpeg" });
    snapshot.on(
      firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
      () => {
        setUploadingImage(true);
        //Alert.alert("Thank you uploading your Gcash proof of payment.")
        // setShowModal_ModeOfPayment(false);
      },
      (error) => {
        setUploadingImage(false);
        console.log(error);
        blob.close();
      
        return;
      },
      () => {
        snapshot.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
          setUploadingImage(false);
          console.log("Download URL: ", url);
          setgcashProoflink_Storage(url);
          setGgcashProofImage(url);
          blob.close();
          Alert.alert("Thank you for uploading the image.");
          return url;
        });
      }
    );
  };


  const handleUploadImage=async()=>{
    //check if the gcashProofImage if naa ba sulod or wala
    if(gcashProofImage===null){
      Alert.alert("Please upload a screenshot of your Gcash payment.");
    }
    else{
      uploadImage();
    }
  }
```

Thank you.